# Tensor Notation Check

Tags: tensors

Let $\mathbf{V}$ be a vector field written in basis $\{x_i\}$, $\rho$ a scalar field, and $V_j$ a scalar field defined as the $j^{\text{th}}$ component of $\mathbf{V}$ at every point in the field.

Is the following true: $$\mathbf{V}\cdot\nabla (\rho V_j)= V_j \nabla\cdot  (\mathbf{V}\rho)$$

The equality of these statements seems strange, I don't know why. Though using tensor notion, I think that the above reduces to $$ V_i (\rho V_j)_{,i} = V_j  V_{,i} \rho_{,i}$$ This doesn't help me much though...

Comment: As it stands, it is incorrect. On the LHS $i$ is the dummy variable and $j$ is fixed, but on the RHS you've turned just switched the two without justification.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. My logic was not quite that I was simply switching the dummy and fixed variables. Instead, the equality results from permuting terms on the RHS of the equation as, in tensor notation, I did not think the order of terms mattered.

Comment: Okay, never mind. I now believe my "tensor notation" to be completely wrong. So that I have some kind of baseline... is the proposed equality even correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. Take $\textbf{V}=(x,y,z)$, $\rho=1$, and, e.g. $j=1$, so $V_j=x$. Then LHS $=x$ but RHS $=3x$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\nabla fg=f\nabla g+g\nabla f$ you can get
$$
\nabla(\rho V_j)=\rho\nabla V_j+V_j\nabla\rho\ .
$$
Again, using the standard chain rule $\nabla\cdot(f\textbf{V})=f\nabla\cdot\textbf{V}+\nabla f\cdot\textbf{V}$, you can find an expression for your $\nabla\cdot(\textbf{V}\rho)$. Can you take it from there?